# Cannot access Video Indexer API?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

I'm trying to use Video Indexer API (v2).  But when I try to sign in to it using the the Azure Active Directory, I get this message:

```
Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft' and cannot access the application 'da0eb6e2-d2bd-4cbd-ad65-81ddc43546e2' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.
```

I'm not sure what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Sign-in to the [VideoIndexer developer portal](https://aka.ms) has been revised.
We unified the developer portal sign-in with that of the [VideoIndexer site](http://videoindexer.ai).

The screenshot in @Mohit_Garg comment in no longer relevant. This is our new sign-in experience.

[image]

The first option should be used in case of Active Directory accounts. This is also the only option that will allow you to use Video Indexer **paid**.

In many cases users selected the Microsoft option in the old authentication method when they actually wanted AAD option.

After the new experience they select the first option "Sign in with a corporate account" and get a message saying that an account with that E-Mail already exit.

An Email is unique in Video Indexer developer portal. So if you want to use your AAD but previously opened an account in the developer portal using a different authentication method you will need to sign-in using the original authentication method and close the account in your [developer profile](https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/developer) page. After the account removal you will be able to sign in with different authentication method.

More info can be found in the [official video indexer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/video-indexer/video-indexer-use-apis)

**Clarification:** I'm a developer in the Video Indexer team.

Comment: Sign-in to the Developer Portal failed.
There is another user with the same email = ‘xxxx@outlook.com’ that is already registered to APIM.
Note: If you have two or more users with the same email, and you want to switch between accounts, you can delete your Developer Portal account and register again.
Back to the Developer Portal

Comment: 1. The videoindexer team has overcomplicated user authentication. There should never be a case where an email should belong to multiple accounts in the same system. 
2. Each account should have a direct link to its own developer portal.

This isn't rocket science.

Comment: The developer portal is another app entirely, which shouldn't be the case. And if it were, the integration and connection should be seamless, not disconnected.

Answer (score -1):

Follow below steps to **Subscribe to the API** -

1. Sign in.
   To start developing with Video Indexer, you must first Sign In to the [Video Indexer](https://videobreakdown.portal.azure-api.net/) portal.

[image]

If signing in with an AAD account (for example, alice@contoso.onmicrosoft.com) you must go through two preliminary steps:

A. Contact us at visupport@microsoft.com to register your AAD organization’s domain (contoso.onmicrosoft.com).

B. Your AAD organization’s admin must first sign in to grant the portal permissions to your org. To do this, the organization's admin must navigate to https://videobreakdown.portal.azure-api.net/signin-callback?provider=Aad, sign in and give consent.

2. Subscribe.
   Select the [Products](https://videobreakdown.portal.azure-api.net/products) tab. Then, select Production and subscribe.

[image]

Once you subscribe, you will be able to see your subscription and your primary and secondary keys. The keys should be protected. The keys should only be used by your server code. They should not be available on the client side (.js, .html, etc.).

[image]

3. Start developing.
   You are ready to start integrating with the API. Find the [detailed description of each Video Indexer REST API](https://videobreakdown.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/582074fb0dc56116504aed75/operations/5857caeb0dc5610f9ce979e4).